# Extracting filenames containing one or more numbers then cat contents to output file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, numbers, cat

If possible, I'm looking for a bash one liner that concatenates all the files in a folder that are labelled `motif<number>.motif` into an `output.txt` file.

I have a few issues I'm struggling with.

A: The `<number>` contained in the filename can be one or two digits long and I don't know how to use regex (or something similar) to get all the files with either one or two digits. I can get the filenames containing single or double digit numbers separately using:

`motif[0-9].motif` or `motif[0-9][0-9].motif`

but can't work out how to get all the files listed together.

B: The second issue I have is I don't know how many files will be in the directory in advance, so I can just use a range of numbers to select the files. This command is in the middle of a long pipeline.

So lets say I have 20 folders:

`motif1.motif
motif2.motif
...
motif19.motif
motif20.motif`

I'd need to `cat >>` the contents of all of them into `output.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
cat motif{[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}.motif > output
```

or with `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
cat motif[0-9]?([0-9]).motif > output
```

Comment: Many Thanks @anubhava, that was exactly what I was looking for!